# react-select focus() doesn't show cursor after change

Tags: reactjs, focus, react-select

As described [in the official documentation for react-select](https://react-select.com/advanced#accessing-internals), I'm trying to use ref and focus() to manually set the focus into the control input field. In most instances it works, but not immediately after selecting an Option from the dropdown.

After selecting an option from the dropdown, the control gets the focus but the cursor doesn't appear. It only appears if you start typing (including hitting the Esc key). On subsequent openings of the menu, the cursor appears along with the focus of the entire control field. Any ideas how to get this working?

I've created a sample code in codesandbox.io [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-focus-uk3ic)

[image]

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { stateOptions } from "./data.js";

class PopoutExample extends Component {
  selectRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    isOpen: false,
    option: undefined,
  };

  toggleOpen = () => {
  const isOpening = !this.state.isOpen;
  this.setState(
    {
      isOpen: isOpening,
    },
() => isOpening && setTimeout(() => this.selectRef.focus(), 400),
);
};

onSelectChange = option => {
  this.toggleOpen();
  this.setState({ option });
};

render() {
  const { isOpen, option } = this.state;
  return (
    <Dropdown
      target={
        <MainButton onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
          {option ? option.label : "Select a State"}
        </MainButton>
      }
    >
      <Select
        menuIsOpen
        ref={ref => {
          this.selectRef = ref;
        }}
        styles={{
          container: provided => ({
          ...provided,
          display: isOpen ? "block" : "none",
        }),
        }}
        onChange={this.onSelectChange}
        options={stateOptions}
        value={option}
        controlShouldRenderValue={false}
      />
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
}

const MainButton = styled.button`
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Dropdown = ({ children, target }) => (
  <div>
    {target}
    {children}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<PopoutExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: What browser are you using ? Because I've just tried your sandbox on Chrome and everything is working (I can see the cursor all the time) as expected.

Comment: @Laura Did you try selecting a different option from the dropdown? I only get the error the first time I open the dropdown after having selected a different option. I'm using Chrome, Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) (on a Mac). Same bug on Firefox 69.0.3 (64-bit) (on a Mac)

Comment: Sorry for delay, here's my behaviour first time works, second does not and all others after work too. From what I understand the pattern is first opening is ok, second opening not but if I close it next reopening will work as expected until I select a value again.

Comment: Would your behaviour also be accurately described by "works every time except the first time after making a selection"?

Comment: Also notice that the bug also exists in the react-select examples. I saw you've opened an issue on github. I'll keep searching for a workaround.

Comment: Could you provide a link of official react-select examples that have this bug? I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: Same as you provided in your question ! In the accessing internals example, it's exactly the behaviour you also have.

Comment: Ah, in deed ! Brilliant. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Add it as an answer and I'll award that answer the bounty.

Comment: I added an issue on github here https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice that the bug also exists in the [official react-select examples](https://react-select.com/advanced#accessing-internals). Even clicking on the `blur` button after the selection is not solving the problem.

There's probably a small different in the code when user `closes` the menu and `saves + automatically closes` action.

I saw you've opened an [issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3832) on github. Let's keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I can offer an alternative to the behaviour you're trying to achieve, instead of hiding the `Select` with css why don't just `mount` / `unmount` it ?

```
class PopoutExample extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
    option: undefined
  };

  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  };

  onSelectChange = option => {
    this.setState({ option, isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { isOpen, option } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dropdown
        target={
          <MainButton onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
            {option ? option.label : "Select a State"}
          </MainButton>
        }
      >
        {isOpen && (
          <Select
            autoFocus
            menuIsOpen
            onChange={this.onSelectChange}
            options={stateOptions}
            value={option}
            controlShouldRenderValue={false}
          />
        )}
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-focus-stackoverflow-hom2h) of my solution.

Comment: Hi @Laura. The idea is of course good, but in my case I need to remember the scroll position of the list when the dropdown is closed and opened again.

Comment: It should be a native feature of `react-select` but unfortunately there's couple of github issues already opened about this not working anymore.